# Unable to find 'api' folder for serverless functions in React webapp

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to implement serverless functions in my React app to handle some 'backend' requests. However, I can't seem to access the 'api' folder to get to my serverless functions - every time I've tried to access it in my app, I get a 404 error.

The steps I've taken are:

1. Added a 'api' directory in my root folder (highest level)
2. Created a 'helloWorld.js' file inside the api directory
3. Added the following code:

   module.exports = (req, res) => {
   res.statusCode = 200;
   res.send({
   message: "helloWorld"
   });
   };
4. Gone to 'localhost:3000/api/helloWorld
5. Nothing comes back, there isn't an error, it just shows as blank..
6. Tried to implement an API call in a separate file called 'earlyAccess' within my API directory, using the Mailchimp API (code I've successfully used before)
7. Called 'fetch' to post the form to the earlyAccess file in my frontend form code - then I've got a '404 not found'

The basic file structure is:

```
Parent directory
   api
   build
   node_modules
   src
   public
   .env / package.json etc
```

I'm hoping there's something really obvious I've done wrong - but why am I not able to access the API directory?

Comment: React is not a backend library

Comment: I know it’s not, hence the serverless functions. I’ve researched them, and it seemed to suggest all that was needed was to add an ‘api’ directory. There’s probably something really obvious I’m missing, but I can’t figure out or find what it is.

Comment: You will need some kind of backend library that supports serverless functions, or a hosting platform that provides them